# Mapping JFreeChart Series Name to Series Index

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm plotting a `TimeTableXYDataset` using a `StackedXYBarRenderer`. Unfortunately the colours of each series change on refresh.

I know how to set colours using the `setSeriesPaint` method of the renderer, but that takes an  integer series index as the argument. I create my datapoints using a string as the series name:

```
ds.add(new SimpleTimePeriod(us.getDate(), 
                            new Date(us.getDate().getTime() + 1000*60)),
       us.getTotal(), us.getName()));
```

How do I discover the mapping between series name and series index so I can call `setSeriesPaint`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest approach is to update a suitable `Map` as the data accumulates. Alternatively, the methods [`getSeriesKey()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeTableXYDataset.html#getSeriesKey%28int%29) and [`indexOf()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/general/AbstractSeriesDataset.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Comparable%29) may be used to convert in either direction. For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.getSeriesCount(); i++) {
    String name = (String) ds.getSeriesKey(i);
    System.out.println(ds.indexOf(name) + ": " + name);
}
```