# Series keeps changing colour upon refresh

Tags: java, jfreechart, series

I have a problem with my JFreechart in that the series colour changes colour after each refresh.

I tried setting the series colour as follows but this doesnt help

```
plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(0)).setSeriesPaint(1, Color.GREEN);
```

I also tried

```
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.GREEN);
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(2, Color.BLUE);
```

The issue sounds very similar to the following problem but i have a category dataset (There are 2 series)

[Previous Stack Overflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082863/mapping-jfreechart-series-name-to-series-index)

The refresh occurs here, but i dont believe this is the problem

```
private void passStingR(StringBuilder retVal) throws BadLocationException, Exception {
int getinitialscrollpos;
getinitialscrollpos = getinitialscrollPosition(scrollSystemDemand);

try {
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chartPanel.getChart().getPlot();//get plot of graph
//System.out.print("Plot Type" + plot);
ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();//get range of axis of graph

System.out.print("Range " + rangeAxis);//get range lower and upper as an array

mapSystemDemand.put(1, rangeAxis);

} catch(Exception e) {
System.out.print("Error has occured");
} finally {
////////////////refresh data////

Document docR = null;

docR = loadXMLFromString(retVal.toString());//pull in the XML data into a new doc
populate1R(docR);

///////////////refresh data/////
tableSystemDemand.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);//prevent user from changing column order now at refresh level
SimpleDateFormat time_formatterR = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String current_time_strR = time_formatterR.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
updatetFieldDG.setText(current_time_strR);
middlePanel.add(scrollSystemDemand,BorderLayout.WEST);
scrollSystemDemand.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(getinitialscrollpos);
System.out.println("End" + getinitialscrollpos);
getTableData(tableSystemDemand);
head(tableSystemDemand);
//revalidate();
createGraphGUI();

if (mapSystemDemand.get(1) != null) {
    System.out.print("get map" + mapSystemDemand.get(1));
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chartPanel.getChart().getPlot();
plot.setRangeAxis(mapSystemDemand.get(1));//get range of axis of graph
}



}
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
chartPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Demand Refresh TimeDate Stamp " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime())));
revalidate();


    }
```

The chart creation is here:

```
private JFreeChart createChart(final CategoryDataset dataset) {

            final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(
                    "FD", // chart title
                    "DT", // domain axis label
                    "Q", // range axis label
                    dataset, // data
                    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // the plot orientation
                    true, // legend
                    true, // tooltips
                    false // urls
            );


chart.getTitle().setPaint(Color.BLACK);
chart.getTitle().setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));

chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

//System.out.print(plot.getDatasetCount());

LegendTitle legend = chart.getLegend();
legend.setPosition(RectangleEdge.RIGHT);
legend.setItemFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 12));

plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.BLACK);
plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.WHITE);

plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.WHITE);//y axis grid line
plot.setDomainGridlinesVisible(true);//y axis grid line true



plot.getDomainAxis().setLowerMargin(0.0);//places category axis starting right up to the vertical axis
plot.getDomainAxis().setUpperMargin(0.0);//places end of category axis right up to the end of the axis
plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryMargin(0.0);
plot.getDomainAxis().setCategoryLabelPositions(CategoryLabelPositions.createUpRotationLabelPositions(20));
Font font3 = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 8);
plot.getDomainAxis().setTickLabelFont(font3);
plot.getRangeAxis().setTickLabelFont(font3);

plot.getDomainAxis().setLabelFont(font3);
plot.getRangeAxis().setLabelFont(font3);


// customise the range axis...
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
// customise the renderer...
LineAndShapeRenderer renderer = (LineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(0)).setSeriesPaint(1, Color.GREEN);
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(1, Color.GREEN);
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(2, Color.BLUE);
//plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(2)).setSeriesPaint(2, Color.RED);
//plot.getRendererForDataset(plot.getDataset(1)).setSeriesPaint(1, Color.RED);

renderer.setShapesVisible(true);
renderer.setDrawOutlines(true);
renderer.setUseFillPaint(true);
renderer.setFillPaint(Color.white);
   chartPanel.setHorizontalAxisTrace(true);
    chartPanel.setVerticalAxisTrace(true);
    revalidate();
return chart;

    }
```

ALTERNATIVELY iS THERE A WAY TO SET THE COLOUR OF THE SERIES BASED ON THE NAME OF THE ITEMS IN THE LEGEND?

Comment: I think the legend gets the color from the renderer; see if you can isolate this in a [mcve].

Comment: @trashgod i will try paste this a lot of the code has an API which is sensitive, so its quite hard to post without posting it all

Comment: @trashgod is it possible to get the name of the series defined by the legend, and then assigning a colour to the name of the series?

Comment: It's the other way around; try a `DrawingSupplier `, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19472524/230513).